# Using Kotlin to parse nested json array/object

Tags: android, arrays, json, kotlin

I've read a few posts on here saying to use gson or something else.
[Android Kotlin parsing nested JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54120451/android-kotlin-parsing-nested-json)

I am planning on switching to gson later but wondering how to parse with kotlin.

JSON object:

```
{
  "childScoresList": [
    {
      "child_id": "1",
      "score_date": "2022-03-27",
      "category_id": "1",
      "category_name": "Preschool Math",
      "classes": [
        {
          "category_name": "Preschool Math",
          "class_name": "Number Blocks",
          "class_id": "1",
          "class_description": "Ones, Tens, Hundreds Blocks used to create given numbers.",
          "skills": [
            {
              "skill_id": "1",
              "skill_name": "Place Value",
              "skill_description": "Knowing the place value of specific elements.",
              "skill_score": "50"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Kotlin code:

```
val obj = JSONObject(response.toString())
val jsonArray = obj.getJSONArray("childScoresList")
for (i in 0 until jsonArray.length()) {
    val categoryName = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("category_name")
}
```

How do I get data in **class_name**?
I tried various things but could not get it to work.

Comment: I'd prefer Jackson - it's the JSON library recommended by Spring.    I'd guess that you have to walk the tree to get to class name: childScoresList[i].classes[j].class_name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must first get JSONArray from the object according to the following code and then access the **class_name** variable

```
val obj = JSONObject(js)
val jsonArray = obj.getJSONArray("childScoresList")
for (i in 0 until jsonArray.length()) {
    val classes = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray("classes")
    for (x in 0 until classes.length()) {
        val categoryName = classes.getJSONObject(x).getString("category_name")
        val className = classes.getJSONObject(x).getString("class_name")
    }
}
```

Comment: How do we parse multiple objects in the array?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky With this line, you can see the objects inside the array:
```val object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i)```